# Problema al llamar un servicio WCF desde un servicio REST en Azure

Tags: rest, docker, wcf, azure, contenedores

Tengo un servicio REST construido en Net Core 2.2 que llama a un servicio WCF externo, bien lo he dockerizado; ejecuto el contenedor desde mi local localhost:8080 y funciona perfecto levanta el servicio REST y cuando invoco el recurso correspondiente que es un GET este se conecta con el servicio WCF y trae los datos sin problema, luego he subido el contenedor a Azure cuando ejecuto el contenedor desde Azure la parte que no tiene que ver con WCF funciona bien, pero cuando llamo al método que llama al servicio WCF me arroja un error 500 Internal Error,  en mi local todo funciono bien llamo al servicio WCF externo sin problemas así que asumo que no es error de mi programa si no de alguna consideración o configuración en Azure podrían ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: y como esta configurado Azure, agrega más información , revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Elenasys, Azure esta tal cual , me refería mas a que de repente tengo que abrir algún puerto en Azure o de repente alguien con experiencia en WCF y Azure  sabía si hay algún bug o issue entre Azure y wcf  y como superarlo por eso preguntaba. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cual es la descripción o código del error? Esta complicado ayudarte con solo saber que da un error 500 ya que puede deberse a 10000 factores diferentes.

Tines habilitado el Insight en tu application en azure para obtener mas info?